# Iam looping through one array and printing frequency as in the second arrary, for loop works fine, however when same code in function not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, for-loop

```
arr1 = [6,12,8,10,20,16]
arr2 = [5,4,3,2,1,5]

arrn=[]
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    for j in range((arr2[i])):
        arrn.append(arr1[i])
print(arrn)


output [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 20, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]
```

---

> *Above code works fine, but when put in function it doesn't  work Please advise where iam going wrong* Here iam try to distribute arr1
> as per frequency in arr2 respective elements, it prints fine, but
> function is return improper result

---

```
x = [6,12,8,10,20,16]
y = [5,4,3,2,1,5]
n = len(x)


def defreq(a,b):
    arrn = []
    for i in range(n):
        print(i,[a[i]],b[i])
        arrn += [a[i]] * b[i]
        return arrn

print(defreq(x,y))

[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: your return statement is in the forloop

Comment: this isnt the same code inside a function, its completely different.

Comment: your logic inside function and outside is different, and hence change is behaviour is expected too. outside you have 2 `for` loop, inside just 1

Answer (score 0):

Your return is within the for loop, and your logic in the function is different to your earlier code outside the function. 
Here is the corrected code:

```
x = [6,12,8,10,20,16]
y = [5,4,3,2,1,5]
n = len(x)

def defreq(a,b):
    arrn = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range((b[i])):
            arrn.append(a[i])
    return arrn

print(defreq(x,y))
```